# Autofac register generic repository where T is not class

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I came across a problem when trying to resolve my generic repositories for database access. When I use these two as repoitory implementation/interface I am not able to resolve e.g. a `IRepository<ICustomer>`:

Interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IDbModel
{ ... }
```

Implementation:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : DbModel
{ ... }
```

But when I replace `IDbModel` and `DbModel` with `class` in both cases it works as expected.

My registration looks like this:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>));
builder.RegisterType<DbModel>().As<IDbModel>();
builder.RegisterType<Customer>().As<ICustomer>();
```

For the sake of completeness, here are the `ICustomer`:

```
public interface ICustomer : IDbModel
{ ... }
```

The `Customer`:

```
public class Customer : DbModel, ICustomer
{ ... }
```

The `IDbModel`:

```
public interface IDbModel
{ ... }
```

And the `DbModel` (I checked if it works when I remove `abstract` but it doesn't):

```
public abstract class DbModel : IDbModel
{ ... }
```

I was wondering if it is possible to make my first attempt working in some way?

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: There is no compiler error. Only an exception is thrown when Autofac tries to resolve `IRepository<ICustomer>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By asking *Autofac* to resolve `IRepository<ICustomer>` it will try to resolve `Repository<ICustomer>` and `ICustomer` is not a `DbModel`

To fix the error you should replace the class type constraint on `IRepository<TModel>` to an interface type constraint.

```
 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> 
    where T : IDbModel 
 { }
```

Comment: The problem is that by using NHibernate, `T` cannot be an interface. But thanks for this hint. I guess my problem is unlikely to be resolved then.

Comment: Found the solution to the problem with NHibernate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368931/nhibernate-queryover-in-generic-method)
So because your answer lead me to this I will accept it as answer. Thx again.